# ESP WiFi in AP mode with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, wifi, esp8266

I want to connect my ESP8266 in AP mode with a Flutter aplication. The idea is the user, first can discover networks and next to connect it for connect to an ESP web server.
I tryied https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_scan and https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot but i got no results. And other package, however many are discontinued or with low support.
Do you have any ideas?